# Python guessing game, counting number of guesses

Tags: python, count, dice

My Intro to Computer Science teacher gave us a dice guessing game challenge, and while I've managed to figure out most of the components, the final piece is to return what the correct number is (once they've guessed it) and the number of tries it took for them to figure it out. My code returns all of that, but it doesn't account for if the person guessing guesses the same number twice. Is there a way to tell them how many guesses it took for them to find a number while disregarding any repeated numbers?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import random

give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")
guess_number = 1

dice = random.randint(1,6)
while give_number != dice:
    if give_number > dice:
        give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too high! Try again!\n ")
        guess_number = guess_number +1
    if give_number < dice:
        give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too low! Try again!\n ")
        guess_number = guess_number +1

print "Congratulations, you were right, the answer was {}! It took you {} tries.".format(dice, guess_number)
```

Comment: fix your indentation. the `if` statements under `while` need to be moved my one tab space

Answer (score 1):

To detect repeated guesses, we have to keep track of all the previous guesses.

We only need to know if a particular number has been guessed before - not how many times it has come up.

This is the perfect place for using a `set` (see the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)).

Begin with an empty set (rather than beginning with `guess_number = 1`), then add each guess to this set.

Once the person has guessed correctly, you can check the size of the set - this is the number of guesses, ignoring duplicates.

Comment: Or use a dictionary to see which number was guessed the most number of time

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a list to append guesses. I changed your code this way (for Python 3 in my case):

```
import random

give_number = int(input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n "))
guess_number = 1
guessList = []
guessList.append(give_number)

dice = random.randint(1,6)
while give_number != dice:
    if give_number > dice:
        give_number = int(input("Sorry, that answer is too high! Try again!\n "))
        #guess_number = guess_number + 1
        if give_number not in guessList:
            guessList.append(give_number)
    if give_number < dice:
        give_number = int(input("Sorry, that answer is too low! Try again!\n "))
        #guess_number = guess_number + 1
        if give_number not in guessList:
            guessList.append(give_number)

if give_number not in guessList:
    guessList.append(give_number)
print ("Congratulations, you were right, the answer was {}! It took you {} tries.".format(dice, len(guessList)))
```

If you want to check if the input is an integer or within your range, you can have a look at this code:

```
import random

def inputIsInt(inpStr): # checks if the input is an integer in range (1, 7).
    try:
        if int(inpStr) in range(1, 7):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False

give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")
while not inputIsInt(give_number):
    print("Sorry, your input is not an integer or out of range")
    give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")

guessList = []
guessList.append(int(give_number))
dice = random.randint(1,6)

while int(give_number) != dice:
    if int(give_number) > dice:
        give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too high! Try again!\n ")
        while not inputIsInt(give_number):
            print("Sorry, your input is not an integer or out of range")
            give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")
        if int(give_number) not in guessList:
            guessList.append(int(give_number))
    if int(give_number) < dice:
        give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too low! Try again!\n ")
        while not inputIsInt(give_number):
            print("Sorry, your input is not an integer or out of range")
            give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")
        if int(give_number) not in guessList:
            guessList.append(int(give_number))

if int(give_number) not in guessList:
    guessList.append(int(give_number))
print ("Congratulations, you were right, the answer was {}! It took you {} tries.".format(dice, len(guessList)))
```

Comment: The code was improved, now is counts only different tries including the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You also could move the guess_number variable outside of the if statement so:

```
    import random

    give_number = input("We will roll a 6 sided dice. What do you think the number will be?\n ")
    guess_number = 0

    dice = random.randint(1,6)
    while give_number != dice:
        guess_number = guess_number + 1
        if give_number > dice:
            give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too high! Try again!\n ")
            #guess_number = guess_number +1
        if give_number < dice:
            give_number = input("Sorry, that answer is too low! Try again!\n ")
            #guess_number = guess_number +1

    print "Congratulations, you were right, the answer was {}! It took you {} tries.".format(dice,guess_number)
```